# return value is showing as string in place of json

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

I am using file get content method to get stats data as below

```
$val = file_get_contents('https://example.com/getStatsData');
```

I am getting output value as below

```
{"msg":"success","data":[[{"stats_abc":"1223","stats_bcd":"55684","stats_cda":"14999","stats_def":232456,"stats_efg":"432868","stats_fgh":"7558","stats_ghi":"3,778.72","stats_date":"20-01-2018 17:00 PM"}],null]}
```

But when I am decoding it as json_decode($val). It is not showing anything.
Can anyone help me to get above data as array/object?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the json or the decode, it works here, so there must be something wrong with the way you show the result of your decoding. Since that code is not present in your question, I can only guess why that is the case... Perhaps use: `print_r(json_decode($val));` instead of what you're doing now?

Comment: Yes KIKO I am using print_r(json_decode($val)); to print value but it is not showing anything

Comment: Well, then there's something wrong with `$val` even tough you say you checked it. The code in your question is incomplete, we can never find your problem this way. I have posted an answer with working, and complete, code.

Answer (score 1):

This does work:

```
<?php

$json = '{
  "msg": "success",
  "data": [
    [{
      "stats_abc": "1223",
      "stats_bcd": "55684",
      "stats_cda": "14999",
      "stats_def": 232456,
      "stats_efg": "432868",
      "stats_fgh": "7558",
      "stats_ghi": "3,778.72",
      "stats_date": "20-01-2018 17:00 PM"
    }], null
  ]
}';

echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($json));
echo '</pre>';
```

and results in:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [msg] => success
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [stats_abc] => 1223
                            [stats_bcd] => 55684
                            [stats_cda] => 14999
                            [stats_def] => 232456
                            [stats_efg] => 432868
                            [stats_fgh] => 7558
                            [stats_ghi] => 3,778.72
                            [stats_date] => 20-01-2018 17:00 PM
                        )
                )
            [1] => 
        )
)
```

just to show that the json itself is fine.

Comment: When I am using $val response as static variable value then json_decode is working but directly it is not

Comment: Echo the `$val` you read directly and compare it carefully with the static variant. Any difference? If there are none it should work.

Comment: Sorry but there is no any differences between two
my output is
|{
 "msg":"success",
 "data":[
  [{
   "stats_abc":"16404",
   "stats_bcd":"55684",
   "stats_cda":"14999",
   "stats_def":232456,
   "stats_efg":"432868",
   "stats_fgh":"7558",
   "stats_ghi":"3,778.72",
   "stats_date":"20-01-2018 18:00 PM"
  }],null
 ]
}

Comment: when I am formatting the same response by online json viewer json_decode() is working else not

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you any further.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :
 i have put you response in local json file and call and it's working fine. check this :

```
<?php
       $val= file_get_contents('http://localhost/j/test.json');
       print_r(json_decode($val,true));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure, $val is not empty.
Then use `json_decode($val, 1)`. This will convert it to associative array, as expected.

Comment: I have used print_r(json_decode($val,true)); but its showing blank